# What component calculates processes schedule

Tags: windows, operating-system

So i know that (in windows atleast) every process has a priority and theres a starvation counter and more that determine what process will get CPU attention next.

It seems a bit wierd if the cpu itself is working on that.
But is determining all of the factor?

Comment: Determining factor of what?

Comment: The component you're asking about is called the "process scheduler" and is part of the kernel.

Comment: See also https://www.reactos.org/wiki/Kernel#Scheduler

Comment: See also https://doxygen.reactos.org/db/d73/thrdschd_8c_source.html